# I'm trying to read CVS file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

1. I'm new to Django trying to read data from CSV file and display data in form of a table using Django templates. Please help me with how I can do it.

My views.py file

```
from fileinput import filename
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def my_view(request):

    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type = 'text/csv',
        headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="birthdeath.csv"'},
    )

    t = loader.get_template('template.txt')
    c = {'data': filename}
    response.readable(t.render(c))

    return response
```

My templates.txt

```
{% for row in data %}

"{{ row.0|addslashes }}", "{{ row.1|addslashes }}",
"{{ row.2|addslashes }}", "{{ row.3|addslashes }}",
"{{ row.4|addslashes }}"

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you write?

Comment: plaese let me add

Comment: You can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from standard library or [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read a csv file